# IMG src weird behaviour inside a single post loop

Tags: php, images

I was trying to sort out the final look the featured image of a single post, so for the purpose wanted to add a class to the img tag. 
However on the way, I run into some weird behaviour while trying to use  **the_post_thumbnail()** function. This is the code that is have and that actually work:

```
    <?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <article class="post">

                     <h2 class="postTitle"><?PHP the_title(); ?></h2>
                     <img class="singleMainImg" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></img>
                     <p class="postinfo">Created on <?php the_time('F j, Y ')?>  at  <?php the_time('g:i a') ?>. <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></p>

                     <?php the_content(); ?>
          </article>
          <?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <?php endwhile;

  else:
    echo '<p> No Content</p>';
  endif;

get_footer();
 ?>
```

the first weird thing is:

```
<img class="singleMainImg" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></img>
```

As you can see I dont have the closing double quotes, and neither  one more ">" after the closing of the php call.

It does work this way and shows as I almost want(I can manipulate the img by the class I assigned.
The problem is its not how the code looks normally without those two closing  things in the img tag.

**The issue I have when I add the closing double quotes, and > in the image tag, I do get them on the actual page as they are, and as extra, right on the next row after the img.**

Also when I try to add some of the pre-defined  image sizes in my functions.php file, as paramater inside the

```
<img class="singleMainImg" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('predefImageSize'); ?></img>
```

it doesnt pulls any image at all

Any idea or explanation or solution to why I am having this issues?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail` function display the post thumbnail i.e. `<img>` tag. You don't need to use `<img>` tag when using this function.

Try this code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="post">
     <h2 class="postTitle"><?PHP the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'predefImageSize', ['class' => 'singleMainImg', 'title' => 'Feature image'] ); ?>
     <p class="postinfo">Created on <?php the_time('F j, Y ')?>  at  <?php the_time('g:i a') ?>. <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></p>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
</article>

<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>

<?php endwhile;

else: echo '<p> No Content</p>';   endif;

get_footer();
```

**Modified Code:**

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'predefImageSize', ['class' => 'singleMainImg', 'title' => 'Feature Image'] ); ?>
```

> Using the array’s keys and values to populate different attributes.
>   You can use this to add classes to the post thumbnail.

**Source**: [the_post_thumbnail documentation at developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

Comment: Thanks man, it does exactly what I need.  Also thanks for the documentation reference, will defo go through it and see what else is there.